# React cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, binding

Moving some code from react.createclass to extending Component i have run into a problem. Whilst mapping a component i have a function being passed through as a property so it could be accessed from that component. It worked find the 'previous way' but now it is throwing this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeComment' of undefined

Initially I thought it just needed binding but with the following code I still get the error: (NB: it fails in the Comment component only - the similar code in CommentForm works as intended)

```
all(value, index) {
    return <Comment author={value.author} key={index} removeComment={this.removeComment.bind(this)} >{value.comment}</Comment>
  }
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          {this.state.items.map(this.all)}
          <CommentForm getNewComment = {this.getNewComment.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      );
  }
```

I have also tried binding it within the constructor method

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all(value, index) {
    return <Comment author={value.author} key={index} removeComment={this.removeComment.bind(this)} >{value.comment}</Comment>
  }
    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          {this.state.items.map(this.all.bind(this))}
          <CommentForm getNewComment = {this.getNewComment.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      );
  }
```

When you run the map you need to bind the handler as map runs the handler in some other scope, and it will change the context of `this`.